# How to fill the empty spaces in the grid in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

As I am displaying the notes on my note taking app, which is a grid, if I have a short note then there is empty space left. How can fill it up by pushing the cards below to go up and stick to card on the top. I am using bootstrap's grid layout for displaying the cards:- [See here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/card/#using-grid-markup)

I also have the screenshot of how the cards are looking currently.
[image: Screenshot]

You can see that there is a gap between the cards and I want to fill it up

Also here is the template of a single card

```js
    let cardTemplate = `<div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">${title.value}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">
                            ${content.value}
                        </p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary showBtn">Show More</a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-danger deleteBtn">Delete</a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-success editBtn">Edit</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>`;
```

and i am putting this card in a div whenever a button is clicked

```html
        <!--displaying notes-->
        <div class="row"></div>
```

I have not done any css on the div since I like the looks as it is.
Thanks for reading my query!

Comment: Try columns instead of grid.

Comment: change <div class="card"> into <div class="card h-100">

Comment: @mrJQuery i know that but still i needed some irregularity in the grid that's why i am doing this

Comment: @phuzi how can i do that?

Comment: Then you should take a look at masonry gird. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/masonry/ this might be something youre looking for. EDIT: Since you're using bootstrap v4: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-columns

Comment: @mrJQuery thank you so much its working but there is another problem when i add a note i dont get the masonry layout right after i have to reload the page first to get that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `masonry`. It's a grid property that allows that exact behavior that you are looking for. It can be done with `grid-template-rows:masonry;`. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KrPz_wmBsAE&ab_channel=KevinPowell) is a link that would tell you exactly how you can do it.

Comment: Thank you so much for letting me know about this and i got the masonry layout by bootstrap itself. But I have to still reload the page after adding the note so that i can get the note

Answer (score 1):

Try adding class **h-100** inside`<div class="card h-100">`** or **h-50** or **h-25**,which makes an element or div as tall with height utilities. it is readily available in bootstrap.

[refer this link for getting more information about pre-defined sizes classes in bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/sizing/)

Comment: Actually i know about that but who likes perfectly arranged grid? A little bit of irregularity  really adds up to the looks!

Comment: If you want to arrange the blocks or cards with different sizes and without spaces then you have to adapt masonry layout.  add grid-template-rows: masonry and grid-column: span 2;
link : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Masonry_Layout